# How to do FFT in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fft

I'm currently trying to do FFT in node.js and having a lot of difficulty.  I've looked through and tried about three different libraries, but every one of them is poorly documented at best, which makes it really difficult.

I have a Float32Array that is downsampled to 44100/16 being sent via websocket to my server, so I have the raw audio data.  The next part is where I need someone with prior experience with any FFT node.js package.

I'm trying to get frequency and magnitude data, I don't much care about phase, but in any case... how to I get a npm FFT package to give me useful data?

Here's what I've got now, and the output it's giving me is absolutely meaningless.  It's not showing me the sine tone it's getting.

```
var fft = require('fft-js').fft,
    fftUtil = require('fft-js').util;

const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss =  new WebSocket.Server({ port: 4321 });


var buffers = [];
var totalBufferSize = 0;

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {


        buffers.push(message);
        totalBufferSize += message.length;




        if(totalBufferSize > 6000) {
            var signal = new Float32Array(totalBufferSize);

            var offset = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < buffers.length; i++) {
                signal.set(buffers[i], offset)
                offset += buffers[i].length;
            }

            buffers = [];
            totalBufferSize = 0;


            // console.log(signal);

            var phasors = fft(signal);

            var frequencies = fftUtil.fftFreq(phasors, 2756), // Sample rate and coef is just used for length, and frequency step
                magnitudes = fftUtil.fftMag(phasors); 

            for(var i = 1; i < magnitudes.length; i++) {
                if(magnitudes[i] > 4000) {
                    console.log(frequencies[i], magnitudes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    ws.send('something');
});
```

The output I'm getting is that the magnitude of everything is over 4000, and also... what a standard magnitude is supposed to be, I have no idea.  My guess would have been 0, or like 1.5 for something loud...  Honestly, I'm completely in the dark here without someone who knows this package or a link to some good documentation.

Anyways, how can I turn my audio data into some frequency information, and what will that information mean (eg. what does a magnitude of 4000 mean)?

Answer (score 1):

Parseval's theorem.  The sum of the squares of the full FFT output array will equal the sum of the squares of all the input numbers.  So maybe youR inputs are bigger that 4000?  Maybe in the range of -32768 to 32767?

Comment: Is this true of both complex and real FFT output arrays?  Or do you mean to say the sum of the squares of magnitudes == sum input^2?

Comment: Aren't the squares of the magnitudes equal to the squares of the components (complex or strictly real)?  So, either way...